# iOS Objective-C logical or on keyboardType

Tags: ios, objective-c

should it not be possible to comparing multiple `textField.keyboardType;`

```
BOOL b = textField.keyboardType == (UIKeyboardTypeDefault || UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable || UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress);
```

I get "**use of logical with constant operand**" on `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That expression will always evaluate to the same thing (assuming you correctly replace the logical operators with bitwise operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest to your attempt, that theoretically accomplishes what you were trying to do (but won't actually work):

```
BOOL b = textField.keyboardType & (UIKeyboardTypeDefault | UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable | UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress);
```

You need to use just one `|` to do bitwise-or, because the `||` does a logical or, which wouldn't accomplish what you want. And then you need to do a bitwise-and (`&`) with that value to yield a non-zero value only if the two have bits in common.

However, the problem with this is that the `UIKeyboardType` enum's values aren't powers of two to allow you to do this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIKeyboardType) {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_1),   // A number pad with a decimal point.
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0),      // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0),    // A default keyboard type with URL-oriented addition (shows space . prominently).

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

};
```

Since they aren't powers of two, each one doesn't have a unique bit, which means doing bitwise-or and then a bitwise-and isn't guaranteed to work, and most of the time won't.

Therefore, you must individually compare each one using equality:

```
BOOL b = (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeDefault) || (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable) || (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correctly, it should be

```
BOOL b = (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeDefault)
        || (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable)
        || (textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress);
```

to check whether the `keyboardType` is equal to one of the 3 values.

Comment: Correct. Chris G., you are trying to do a bit comparison which is only available for `NSOption` constructs with operator `|`. Standard OR-comparison should look as in Sulthan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether keyboardType is one of the listed values, use

```
BOOL b = textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeDefault || textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable || textField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
```